# Angular webpack - how do you rewrite URLs?

Tags: angular, webpack, routes

As I understand it from other SO posts, if you try to browse directly to a URL on Angular it will fail with a 404 because that is handled by the backend webserver. In Angular's case, the default webserver is webpack.

The [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml) lists how to setup URL rewriting for several applications but it seems like they don't provide an example for webpack.

I've seen posts about using `ng eject` but when I try to do that I receive:

```
npx -p @angular/cli ng eject
The specified command ("eject") is invalid. For a list of available options,
run "ng help".

Did you mean "e2e"?
```

How does one tell webpack to rewrite a URL?

Comment: webpack is build+dev tool which angular cli uses internally. BE server can be Tomcat or whatever else and there is no "default". And as far as I remember redirecting all 404 to index.html is default for webpack -- that is usually enough.

Comment: That doesn't appear to be what happens. When I enter a random URL the console issues a whole bunch of 404s and goes nowhere

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting confused.

Angular is a frontend framework **and there's no backend URL redirection**. Angular-CLI uses webpack as it's bundler and sets up a **development server** which ALWAYS loads `/` or `/index.html`.

Once that is done, the Single Page App boots up and the in-app (angular router) takes over and starts loading (or lazy-loading if you configured) the different modules and components based on where you are. All that happens on the client side; the user's browser.

Of course when a user types a custom URL on the browser that's going to load the "desired" HTML document on the server: but in Angular it's different. There's just an `index.html` that "evolves" into the desired page.

So how do we solve the problem of loading the desired page if the user typed `http://host.com/a/nested/url`? Because that's gonna return 404 if we just have an `index.html` file at the root

Well depends on the **webserver** you're using and solution varies whether it's an NGINX, IIS, Phoenix... You name it.

Essentially all solutions consist in indicating the webserver to always serve the built `index.html` file by angular. Send that back to the browser and let the angular router figure out which components to load based off that

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not confused about that. For development I want to be able to be able to send a URL to webpack and have it pass that full URL as an argument into Angular whereupon I will then handle it. For example: I have a webpage that links to the Angular app that *isn't* Angular. I need that app, in the development environment, to be able to pass an argument via URL

Comment: You may send that parameter as a URL query parameter and read that from `ActivatedRoute` or the `ActivatedRouteSnapshot`. And you can just set the URL yourself to something like: `http://localhost:4200/fancy-route?nextUrl=http://other.domain.com/`. If you have in-between redirections make sure to set the options in the `NavigateExtras` to `queryParamsHandling: 'merge'`